# the width of the image in Firefox is different from the inserted

Tags: html, css, firefox

Hello everyone I am using jcrop and I'm using Firefox as browser but I noticed that the size of the image does not reflect the actual size I'll explain

the image is not actually 768 but 20% larger than leave below the images

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iI6UH.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xCzf.jpg

Comment: post all of your code, edit your question and hit CTRL + M and paste the code

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your browser's zoom level is set to 120%.  (Press <kbd>Ctrl-0</kbd> to restore to 100%)  If that's not it, check for some parent element's style and look for "zoom: 1.2" or "transform: scale(1.2)".

Comment: NO NOT THIS THE PROBLEM IS TO 100%

Answer (score -1):

update 2:
I created a simple html page inside

```
<IMG src="1.jpg" style="width:423px;height:auto;">
```

and the result is

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKZ94.png

Comment: You need to put this update by editing your question, not putting this update as an answer.

Comment: i cant upload more image!